# XSLT: Defining and using XSL global variables for a Model with a header and List<lines>

Tags: xml, xslt

This is the first time I've worked with XSLT files to transform from JSON to XML and I'm having an issue with a few of the "header" level properties that I want to use in the for-each section, populating the lines.

There are a number of variables that are defined at the "order" level  that I want to populate elements at the line level, but I can't figure out how to make that work. When I transform the JSON, the elements in the line are not populated.

Are the variables I have defined at the order level not considered global? I'm not getting an error in VS when I've added those variables to the line level, so it's recognizing the variable, but it's not populating the line level elements. I tried moving the variables above the match="Order", but that didn't seem to work either.

I hope I'm giving you enough information to see what I'm trying to do. If you have any suggestions, I would appreciate it!

Here's a sample input JSON and the XSLT:

```json
{
    "idocId": "?_365000032042-638019396012813477-s",
    "transferOrderNumber": "000032042",
    "region": "EU",
    "movementType": "952",
    "customerNumber": "1234",
    "transactionCode": "MIGO",
    "receivedAndShippedDate": "20210823",
    "shippedQuantity": 2,
    "receivingCustomerNumber": "5678",
    "shippingCustomerNumber": "1234",
    "legalEntity": "4020",
    "lines": [{
            "unitOfEntryQuantity": 2,
            "materialVariant": {
                "upc": "123456789012",
                "materialNumber": "1930471353",
                "style": "1930471",
                "color": "353",
                "dimension": "",
                "size": "XXL",
                "quality": "V1",
                "masterSkuFlag": null
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

XSLT:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
    xmlns:var="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/var"
    exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl var userCSharp"
    version="1.0"
                
    xmlns:ns0="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Idoc/3/_x002F_AFS_x002F_WMMBID02/Z_x002F_AFS_x002F_WMMBID02/702/Send"
    xmlns:ns1="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/3/_x002F_AFS_x002F_WMMBID02/Z_x002F_AFS_x002F_WMMBID02/702"
    xmlns:ns2="http://Microsoft.LobServices.Sap/2007/03/Types/Idoc/Common/"
    xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/"
    xmlns:userCSharp="http://sapinventory.helpers.XsltExtensionFunctions/1.0">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="xml" version="1.0" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/Order" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/Order">
        <xsl:variable name="varIdocId" select="idocId/text()" />
        <xsl:variable name="varOrderNumber" select="transferOrderNumber/text()" />
        <xsl:variable name="varShipDate" select="receivedAndShippedDate/text()" />
        <xsl:variable name="varTransactionCode" select="transactionCode/text()" />
        <xsl:variable name="varPlant" select="userCSharp:Plant(legalEntity/text())" />
        <xsl:variable name="varMovementType" select="./movementType/text()" />
        <xsl:variable name="varCustomerNumber" select="customerNumber/text()" />
        <xsl:variable name="varReceivingCustomerNumber" select="receivingCustomerNumber/text()" />
        <xsl:variable name="varShippingCustomerNumber" select="shippingCustomerNumber/text()" />
        <ns0:Send>
            <ns0:idocData>
                <ns1:EDI_DC40>
                    <ns2:DOCREL>
                        <xsl:text>702</xsl:text>
                    </ns2:DOCREL>
                    <ns2:DIRECT>
                        <xsl:text>2</xsl:text>
                    </ns2:DIRECT>
                    <ns2:IDOCTYP>
                        <xsl:text>/AFS/WMMBID02</xsl:text>
                    </ns2:IDOCTYP>

                    <ns2:CIMTYP>
                        <xsl:text>Z/AFS/WMMBID02</xsl:text>
                    </ns2:CIMTYP>

                    <ns2:MESTYP>
                        <xsl:text>WMMBXY</xsl:text>
                    </ns2:MESTYP>
                    <ns2:MESCOD>
                        <xsl:text>EUR</xsl:text>
                    </ns2:MESCOD>

                    <ns2:MESFCT>
                        <xsl:text>EUC</xsl:text>
                    </ns2:MESFCT>

                    <ns2:SNDPOR>
                        <xsl:text>ODP</xsl:text>
                    </ns2:SNDPOR>

                    <ns2:SNDPRT>
                        <xsl:text>LS</xsl:text>
                    </ns2:SNDPRT>
                    <ns2:SNDPRN>
                        <xsl:text>ODP</xsl:text>
                    </ns2:SNDPRN>
                    <ns2:RCVPOR>
                        <xsl:text>ODP</xsl:text>
                    </ns2:RCVPOR>
                    <ns2:RCVPRT>
                        <xsl:text>LS</xsl:text>
                    </ns2:RCVPRT>
                    <ns2:RCVPRN>
                        <xsl:text>ODP</xsl:text>
                    </ns2:RCVPRN>
                    <ns2:ARCKEY>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$varIdocId" />
                    </ns2:ARCKEY>
                </ns1:EDI_DC40>

                <!--- Begin Movement -->
                <ns1:E2MBXYH002GRP>
                    <ns1:E2MBXYH002>
                        <ns1:DATAHEADERCOLUMN_SEGNAM>
                            <xsl:text>E2MBXYH002</xsl:text>
                        </ns1:DATAHEADERCOLUMN_SEGNAM>

                        <ns1:BLDAT>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$varShipDate" />
                        </ns1:BLDAT>

                        <ns1:BUDAT>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$varShipDate" />
                        </ns1:BUDAT>

                        <ns1:TCODE>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$varTransactionCode" />
                        </ns1:TCODE>

                        <ns1:USNAM>
                            <xsl:text>BizTalk</xsl:text>
                        </ns1:USNAM>

                        <ns1:XBLNR_LONG >
                            <xsl:value-of select="$varOrderNumber" />
                        </ns1:XBLNR_LONG >
                    </ns1:E2MBXYH002>
l
                <xsl:for-each select="lines">
                    <xsl:variable name="lineQuantity" select="unitOfEntryQuantity/text()" />
                    <xsl:variable name="lineQuality" select="materialVariant/quality/text()" />
                    <xsl:variable name="lineUpc" select="materialVariant/upc/text()" />
                    <ns1:E2J3XYI003GRP>
                        <ns1:E2J3XYI003>

                            <ns1:DATAHEADERCOLUMN_SEGNAM>
                                <xsl:text>E2J3XYI003</xsl:text>
                            </ns1:DATAHEADERCOLUMN_SEGNAM>

                            <!-- Plant Number -->
                            <ns1:WERKS>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$varPlant"/>
                            </ns1:WERKS>

                            <!--  Movement Type -->
                            <ns1:BWART>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$varMovementType"/>
                            </ns1:BWART>

                            <!-- Stock Indicator -->
                            <ns1:SOBKZ>
                                <xsl:text>W</xsl:text>
                            </ns1:SOBKZ>

                            <ns1:LGORT>
                            </ns1:LGORT>

                            <!-- Customer Number -->
                            <ns1:KUNNR>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$varCustomerNumber" />
                            </ns1:KUNNR>

                            <!-- Customer Number -->
                            <ns1:WEMPF>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$varReceivingCustomerNumber" />
                            </ns1:WEMPF>

                            <ns1:ABLAD>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$varShippingCustomerNumber" />
                                        
                            </ns1:ABLAD>

                            <!-- Partner Account Number -->
                            <ns1:VPTNR>
                                <xsl:text>BizTalk</xsl:text>
                            </ns1:VPTNR>

                            <!-- Quantity -->
                            <ns1:ERFMG>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$lineQuantity" />
                            </ns1:ERFMG>

                            <ns1:SGTXT>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$varOrderNumber" />
                            </ns1:SGTXT>

                            <!-- Quality Identification -->
                            <ns1:J_4KSCAT>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$lineQuality" />
                            </ns1:J_4KSCAT>

                        </ns1:E2J3XYI003>

                        <ns2:ZE1J3XYI000>
                            <ns2:DATAHEADERCOLUMN_SEGNAM>
                                <xsl:text>ZE1J3XYI000</xsl:text>
                            </ns2:DATAHEADERCOLUMN_SEGNAM>
                            <ns2:ZZEAN11>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$lineUpc" />
                            </ns2:ZZEAN11>
                        </ns2:ZE1J3XYI000>

                        <ns1:E2MBXYJ001>
                            <ns1:DATAHEADERCOLUMN_SEGNAM>
                                <xsl:text>E2MBXYJ001</xsl:text>
                            </ns1:DATAHEADERCOLUMN_SEGNAM>
                            <ns1:MENGE>
                                <xsl:text></xsl:text>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$lineQuantity" />
                            </ns1:MENGE>
                        </ns1:E2MBXYJ001>
                    </ns1:E2J3XYI003GRP>
                </xsl:for-each>
                    
                </ns1:E2MBXYH002GRP>
            </ns0:idocData>
        </ns0:Send>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's not at all clear to me what you are having difficulty with. It looks to me like you have a template matching `Order` elements, and you want to capture the value of some of the child elements of `Order` in variables, and then use those variables while processing the `line` child elements of `Order`? That is absolutely straightforward to do, and I don't see what your problem is. But it's hard to say because you have not provided source XML and your XSLT is not well-formed. You're missing a closing `>` on your root element, and missing namespace declarations.

Comment: My advice is: 1) fix up the stylesheet above by adding the missing `>` and adding the missing xmlns declarations for `ns0`, `ns1`, and `ns2` to the `xsl:stylesheet` element. Then add some sample input data and desired output in separate code blocks.

Comment: My apologies, I was trying to cut down the size for displaying. I've updated the post with the full xslt.

Comment: NB an XSLT 1.0 stylesheet necessarily requires input in XML format, not JSON. How are you converting the JSON to XML? Can you show the XML that provides the input to the XSLT? And can you provide a sample of what output you want to see (at least the part you are having problems with)?

Comment: The most likely reason for a variable not having a value is using a wrong path when defining the variable. And the most likely reason for the path being wrong is ignoring the namespace/s in the input XML. Of course, without seeing the input XML, we can only guess. Please provide a way for us to reproduce the problem. And also reduce the code to the minimum required - see: [mcve].

Comment: If you use [XSLT for JSON](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#json) then the structure of xml is not what you expect : you will have to manage map/array/string records with @key attributes.